# Comparing time using strtotime to disable option

Tags: php

Want to make sure this statement is accurate, I've been having problems with it working on a larger scale with more if statements. Im trying to have this option enable by checking the current time and comparing it to the start time (wednesday at 6:00am) and then checking the current time and comparing it to the close time(Saturday at 7:00pm), if it is within that time block then it should be clickable but if not then disabled. I realize this is a simple question but I just want to be sure.

```
<?php
    $current = strtotime('Now'); // Current date/time
    $start = strtotime('6:00am Wednesday'); // Wednesday morning Picks open
    $close = strtotime('7:00pm Saturday'); // Sunday night game time

if(($current < $start) && ($close > $current)){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = '';}echo '<option value="Washington Redskins"'.$dis.'>Washington Redskins</option>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be or close < current:

```
if(($current < $start) || ($close < $current)) {
    $dis = ' disabled';
} else {
    $dis = '';
}
```

Because you want it disabled if it hasn't started yet OR it has closed.